# How check consistency npm-shrinkwrap.json and package.json

Tags: node.js, githooks, npm-shrinkwrap, package-lock.json

Sometimes my team members forgot to update npm-shrinkwrap.json after update package.json. I know [this package](https://github.com/uber/npm-shrinkwrap) from uber, but it can not be used with npm v3. So now it is not solution.

Do have I possibility to auto check consistency for npm-shrinkwrap.json and package.json? I want to do this in git-hook or/and continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update from 24 jun 2017**
The modern answer is to use npm 5 with `package-lock.json`

Answer (score 1):

You can test out the [npm package `git-hooks`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-hooks), which allows to install [pre-commit or pre-push hooks](https://github.com/tarmolov/git-hooks-js/tree/master/examples) (that is [client-side hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks))

Such hooks (like this [pre-commit one](https://github.com/tarmolov/git-hooks-js/blob/master/examples/pre-commit/test)) can be used to check the consistency of source files like `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.

See also for instance [`turadg/npm-shrinkwrap-git-hooks`](https://github.com/turadg/npm-shrinkwrap-git-hooks)

> A set of scripts to automatically `npm shrinkwrap` and `npm install` as needed.
>
> If you stage a change to `package.json`, the `pre-commit` hook will `run npm shrinkwrap` to update `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This ensures that dependencies are installed locally whenever merging a commit
# that changed the shrinkwrap.

function package_changes_staged {
  ! git diff --cached  --quiet -- package.json
}

# update shrinkwrap when spec changes
if package_changes_staged; then
  echo "Running 'npm shrinkwrap' to match new package spec..." >&2
  npm shrinkwrap
  git add npm-shrinkwrap.json
fi
```

**UPDATE** by galk-in

I chose [pre-commit](http://npmjs.com/pre-commit) with this updates in package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
  "check-shrinkwrap": "if (! git diff --cached  --quiet -- package.json); then echo 'Running `npm shrinkwrap` to match new package spec...' >&2; npm shrinkwrap; git add npm-shrinkwrap.json; fi"
},
...
"pre-commit": [
  "check-shrinkwrap",
  "test"
]
...
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea about CI solution?

Comment: @galk.in Sure. you can integrate that in a Travis CI environment for instance (https://pub.clevertech.biz/faster-node-js-builds-with-travis-ci-41aa275015e7#.dqvjoo41f)

Comment: @galk.in you can see your issue discussed in the context of another CI: greekeeper: https://github.com/greenkeeperio/greenkeeper/issues/96